# Syncing iPhone contacts to Google so I can have them in my Galaxy Tab S

Tags: contacts, sync, google, ios

I still currently have a iPhone and I want to sync my iPhone contacts to my tablet to through google. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Transferring with Gmail and iTunes
First, you’re going to need a Gmail account, which will make moving contacts to any platform simple. If you don’t have a Gmail account, quickly sign-up for one on Gmail’s homepage. Before you even touch your new Android phone, plug your old iPhone into your computer and open iTunes. Then, find the Info tab on the menu bar at the top of the window. In the drop-down menu next to the “Sync Contacts With” box, select Google Contacts, and then type in your Gmail account information in the window which appears. This allows Gmail and Apple to update your contacts so all of the names, numbers, and emails from your phone’s contacts are now stored in your Google account.